# wolframlanguage.stackexchange.com should redirect to this site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems that the language we use in *Mathematica* is officially named the Wolfram Language, as seen on [the official site](https://www.wolfram.com/language/). Since this site is for users to ask questions pertaining to the Wolfram Language and since the terms Wolfram Language and *Mathematica* are often interchangeable, I believe that wolframlanguage.stackexchange.com domain should redirect here, just like how [mathematics.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) redirects to the [Math Stack Exchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Or perhaps, this site could be renamed to wolframlanguage.stackexchange.com; the current name is misleading because it may imply that only questions on the *Mathematica* software are allowed, which is not true. The majority of the questions here is on coding in the Wolfram Language, nor do we restrict questions about coding on other platforms such as Wolfram Desktop, Wolfram Development Platform, etc.

I believe wolframlanguage.stackexchange.com is a more accurate name for this site, showing that all questions involving the Wolfram Language are allowed.

Plus, wouldn't this solve the current issue about too many people asking math questions here?

Comment: [A related discussion.](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1152) My personal opinion: I would not mind an additional redirect URL, but will strenuously object to renaming the site to Wolfram Language Stack Exchange.